# Select rows from table where all columns in another are set

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have been trying to figure this out for a long time and just cant seem to get it. I have two tables and need to select DISTINCT from Table 1 only when all columns in Table 2 match a criteria, Here is how the tables look:

```
Table 1
ACR     OCD
sea     123
sea     456
sfo     678
sfo     890

Table 2
OCD       SWITCH
123        Y
456        N
678        Y
890        Y
```

I am trying to write a select statement that would return Table1.ACR only if all of the switches are set to Y for all OCD's that belong to that ACR in Table 1. So, with this data example it would return sfo because OCD 678 and 890 are both set to Y in Table 2.

I  have tried:

```
SELECT t1.acr
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.ocd NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT t1.ocd
                     FROM table1 t1
                       JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ocd=t2.ocd
                     WHERE t2.swtich = 'Y');
```

This returns:

```
sea
sfo
sfo
```

Comment: What if an ACR has no row in table2?

Comment: Good question, but in this case it is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT t1.acr
FROM table1 t1
     LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t2.ocd = t1.ocd AND t2.switch = 'Y'
GROUP BY t1.acr
HAVING COUNT(t2.ocd) = COUNT(t1.ocd)
```

Comment: Works perfect! Just changed it to match my actual tables....only problem I have now is that table1 may have more OCDs than table2 because we have a clos_dt where we can close one.

Comment: I assume clos_dt is the date closed. You can filter table1 by clos_dt in the WHERE clause: `WHERE clos_dt IS NULL`

Comment: Or if you prefer to not show OCDs that do not exist in table2, add another condition in the HAVING clause: `HAVING COUNT(t2.ocd) = COUNT(t1.ocd) AND COUNT(t2.ocd)>0`